# ERROR:The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. (even though there is a secret key in my settings.py file )

Tags: django, django-settings, secret-key

getting django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
this error even though i have a secret key assigned in my settings.py file

i have tried changing this code of line

## `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')`

to

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'scrapshut.settings'
```

i have tried to set environmnet variable

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
django-admin runserver
```

and when i run the server with that following command i just get

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing se
ttings.
```

this error 
and whenever i run manage.py runserver command im still getting the same error (no secret_key)

i dont know what's the reason and why django isnt able to find my secret_key

Comment: Are you really sure you have SECRET_KEY in your "scrapshut.settings"?

Comment: And why do you need two settings files?

Comment: yes..... @Newell  i have secret_key in my settings.py file

Comment: i dont have two settings file,i just have one